# Add custom control to toolbox and have its properties show up in the properties window

Tags: vba, excel

To illustrate what I'm asking, let's say I have a custom TextBox that has 2 modes. Mode 1  only allows numbers, and mode 2 only allows dates in a particular format.

Using a class module I can create this custom TextBox, and I can use a loop when the userform initialises to set which TextBoxes are custom.

What I'd like to happen is have the custom TextBox, or what ever custom control I want, show up in the toolbox. And I also want its custom properties, if they exist, to show up in the property window.

So far, I've been unable to find a way to do this. In fact, I've been unable to find out if it's even possible. It seems, to me anyway, that it's something that *should* be possible, but maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree. If it's possible I'd really appreciate being pointed to a resource.

Comment: I don't think that you can do it using the VBA but you should be able to do it VB 6[Microsft Create a custom ActiveX control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa239763(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: I agree with Thomas Inzina you need to compile to an ActiveX control, VB6 is history now, so VB.NET (or C#).

Comment: Thanks folks, that's given me something to play around with. I was kinda hoping that I could drop a module in a folder somewhere lol, oh well.